# 100% training and valuation accuracy, tried gradient clipping too

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I get always 100% training and validation accuracies. Here's how it looks:

```
Epoch 17/20
27738/27738 [==============================] - 228s 8ms/step - loss: 4.1600e-05 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.6773e-05 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 18/20
27738/27738 [==============================] - 229s 8ms/step - loss: 3.6246e-05 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.0900e-05 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 19/20
27738/27738 [==============================] - 221s 8ms/step - loss: 3.1839e-05 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 3.6044e-05 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 20/20
27738/27738 [==============================] - 7616s 275ms/step - loss: 2.8176e-05 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 3.1987e-05 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

Here's the whole code for the process:

```
encoder_input_sequences = pad_sequences(input_integer_seq, maxlen=max_input_len)
decoder_input_sequences = pad_sequences(output_input_integer_seq, maxlen=max_out_len, padding='post')
import numpy as np
read_dictionary = np.load('/Users/Downloads/wordvectors-master/hinvec.npy',allow_pickle='TRUE').item()
num_words = min(MAX_NUM_WORDS, len(word2idx_inputs) + 1)
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, EMBEDDING_SIZE))
for word, index in word2idx_inputs.items():
    embedding_vector = read_dictionary.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words, EMBEDDING_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_input_len)
decoder_targets_one_hot = np.zeros((
        len(input_sentences),
        max_out_len,
        num_words_output
    ),
    dtype='float32'
)
decoder_targets_one_hot.shape
encoder_inputs_placeholder = Input(shape=(max_input_len,))
x = embedding_layer(encoder_inputs_placeholder)
encoder = LSTM(LSTM_NODES, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, h, c = encoder(x)
encoder_states = [h, c]
decoder_inputs_placeholder = Input(shape=(max_out_len,))
decoder_embedding = Embedding(num_words_output, LSTM_NODES)
decoder_inputs_x = decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs_placeholder)decoder_lstm = LSTM(LSTM_NODES, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs_x, initial_state=encoder_states)

###########################from here I add activation function and apply some parameters:
decoder_dense = Dense(num_words_output, activation='sigmoid')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipvalue=1.0)
model = Model([encoder_inputs_placeholder,
  decoder_inputs_placeholder], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
history = model.fit(
    [encoder_input_sequences, decoder_input_sequences],
    decoder_targets_one_hot,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_split=0.1,
)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.show()
```

EDIT:
I changed following piece of code:

```
decoder_targets_one_hot.shape
############################ Added this
decoder_output_sequences = pad_sequences(output_integer_seq, maxlen=max_out_len, padding='post')
for i, d in enumerate(decoder_output_sequences):
    for t, word in enumerate(d):
        decoder_targets_one_hot[i, t, word] = 1
#############################
encoder_inputs_placeholder = Input(shape=(max_input_len,))
```

I think its the right approach but I'm still getting 100% accuracies. is this the correct way to implement? Btw here's the link to tutorial if u wanna get idea about the output im following, only difference is my dataset is eng-hin instead of eng-fra: https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-neural-machine-translation-with-seq2seq-in-keras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `decoder_targets_one_hot` as vectors of zeros, but do not set the index of true class as `1` anywhere. So, basically the target vectors are not one-hot vectors. The model tries to learn same target for all inputs, i.e. the vector of zeros.

Comment: how can I modify my code?do you mean I need to add something like this ` for i, d in enumerate(decoder_output_sequences): for t, word in enumerate(d): decoder_targets_one_hot[i, t, word] = 1`?

Comment: I don't know about the data you use and how the targets should look like, but yes, you should set the correct classes as `1`. Let's say there are three classes and third class is the true label for a given input `x`. Then the target vector must be equal to `[0 0 1]`

Comment: I added but probably I failed to implement it properly. I edited the post, can you take a look at that link to get an idea what I might be doing wrong?